# aspose slides cannot load powerpoint files with an embedded chart

Tags: java, aspose, aspose-slides

Does anybody here encountered using java aspose slides library that it cannot load a PPTX file with an embedded chart on it?

I use Apsose-slide version 23.10, 23.11, and 23.12

Here is the snippet:

```
Presentation presentation = new Presentation(pptfile.getPath());
```

I got this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" class com.aspose.slides.PptxReadException: Cannot invoke "com.aspose.slides.internal.ld.cf.dq()" because the return value of "com.aspose.slides.internal.ld.td.dq()" is null ---> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.aspose.slides.internal.ld.cf.dq()" because the return value of "com.aspose.slides.internal.ld.td.dq()" is null
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
com.aspose.slides.qge.dq(Unknown Source)
com.aspose.slides.Presentation.nx(Unknown Source)
com.aspose.slides.Presentation.dq(Unknown Source)
com.aspose.slides.Presentation.dq(Unknown Source)
com.aspose.slides.Presentation.<init>(Unknown Source)
com.aspose.slides.Presentation.<init>(Unknown Source)
jp.co.vpj.converter.SlideReader.convertToJpeg(SlideReader.java:73)
jp.co.vpj.converter.Main.start(Main.java:160)
jp.co.vpj.converter.Main.main(Main.java:99)
    at com.aspose.slides.qge.dq(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.slides.Presentation.nx(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.slides.Presentation.dq(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.slides.Presentation.dq(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.slides.Presentation.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.slides.Presentation.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at jp.co.vpj.fileconverter.SlideReader.convertToJpeg(SlideReader.java:73)
    at jp.co.vpj.fileconverter.Main.start(Main.java:160)
    at jp.co.vpj.fileconverter.Main.main(Main.java:99)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.aspose.slides.internal.ld.cf.dq()" because the return value of "com.aspose.slides.internal.ld.td.dq()" is null
    at com.aspose.slides.oyy.dq(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.slides.oyy.dq(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.slides.oyy.dq(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.slides.rz.ot(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.slides.rz.dq(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.slides.d2.dq(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.slides.lm.dq(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.slides.b6.dq(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.slides.w4.dq(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.slides.b6.dq(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.slides.b6.dq(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.slides.dz.dq(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.slides.szq.dq(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.slides.nw3.dq(Unknown Source)
    at com.aspose.slides.qge.gj(Unknown Source)
    ... 9 more
```